Livewire action restricting 3rd part plugin intialization
i'm using a 3rd party scrollbar plugin (smooth-scrollbar) in my php code and it is working fine when loading page, after any livewire click or action happened (like pagination or sorting) inside a table happened suddenly the scrollbar plugin content is getting removed. Any idea what is the issue behind this. Any fix for that?
function scrollInitialize() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(elements[i], {
            damping: 0.5, // Set damping to 0.5
            renderByPixels: true, // Render scrollbars by pixels
            continuousScrolling: true, // Enable continuous scrolling
            alwaysShowTracks: true
        });

        
    }
}

function init() {
    // ========================================================
    // Condition based on screen width
    // ========================================================
    if (mq.matches) {
        
        // ========================================================
        // Smooth Scrollbar
        // ========================================================

        // Initialize Smooth Scrollbar for all elements with the class 'scroll'
        scrollInitialize();

    }
}

This is the initilization code
HTML Code:
<div class="table-responsive scroll">
     <table class="cs-table table caption-top main-listing" id="dropdown-options-table"></table>
</div>

